# How to force the Application deployed in WAS servers to use default trust store trust.p12 (Node) rather than refer to java cercets

Tags: spring, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, websphere

My Rest Template is referring to java_1.8_192/jre/lib/security/cacerts rather than it is not referring to WAS default trust store. Below are the code snippet i am using. How to force the code to check default WAS node level trust store.

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().build();
SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory( sslContext, new String[] { "TLSv1.2", "TLSv1.1" },null, SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getDefaultHostnameVerifier() ); 
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory( sslConnectionSocketFactory ).build(); 
ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory( client );
```

Comment: If you want use default truststore, then do not create custom sslContext/settings but use defaults one. In that case it will pick up WAS provded.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the APIs your using above but as mentioned in the last comment you should not create a custom SSLContext/setting then expect WebSphere to be used.   If you use the HttpClientBuilder with the useSystemProperties() options you code will likely pick up the WebSphere configurations.